# Show Account's contacts' chatter feed on account's feed

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

Is there a way for contacts who are tied to an account to have their chatter activity appear on the account chatter feed?

Comment: it is doable by building a VF page and creating a quick actions, how do you   want to handle multiple contacts associated with an Account?

Comment: I want all contact activity to appear on the account. This is for a small non profit so accounts are just households and contacts are household members who use the service @Rao

Comment: If this is a non profit, can you still use Apex. I know some versions have limitations based on edition if so I can provide a solution